# All combinations of two arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am reposting this, reworded, as the initial question didn't make much sense written down.

I am trying to write a little piece of code that will add maths questions to a database. These ones are ratio questions.

For instance I want to add lots of questions like 'Simplify 10: 6' and store the answer as '5 : 3'.

I was thinking the best thing to do would be store the digits as an array, and the early primes as an array (I only want prime multiples for now).

I could then loop though this array. This I can do. However, I want every single possible combination of my digits, not just to loop through the array once.

For instance I want the questions 
2 : 4 , 3: 6, 5 : 10, 7: 14 etc etc

So I want to pair digits[0...8] with every other digit, and then loop though the primes multiplying these combinations with every prime. I get that this would probably be some kind of nested for loop, but i've not really got much of an idea where to start.

This is what I have so far. It does exactly nothing. I realise it would have been quicker to manually input all there but I want to learn a bit of coding, too.

```
   $digits = array(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
   $primes = array(2,3,5,7,11);

   for ($first = 0; $first < count($digits)-1; $first++) {
         $num1 = $digits[$first];
      for ($second = 1; $second < count($digits)-2; $second++) {
         $num2 = $digits[$second];
            for ($third = 0; $third < count($primes)-1; $third++) {
         $num3 = $num1 * $primes[$third];
         $num4 = $num2 * $primes[$third];

         $questionlead = "Simplify <br>" .$num3. " : " . $num4 ;
         $ans = $num1. " : " . $num2 ;

   $dbhost = 'nope';
   $dbuser = 'notfor';
   $dbpass = 'you';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = "INSERT INTO QuestionDB(TopicID, TopicName, SubtopicID, SubtopicName, Question, Answer, Difficulty, Author, Projectable) VALUES (6,'Ratio',1,'Simplifying ratio','".$questionlead. "','".$ans. "',1,'Richard Tock','Yes')";
   mysql_select_db('db_name');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

      }
}
}
   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I'm lost at sea here

Comment: I get that you want to use prime factorization to reduce your fractions to the lowest common denominator, but I have to wonder why you then want to go backwards and generate every possible equivalence. That's an infinite set that reduces to the result you've already calculated.

Comment: Not quite infinite. I want to put a boundary on it. I want to generate a set of questions, that would then be projected. I have done the same thing with multiplication questions here http://ticktockmaths.co.uk/TimedQuestions/index.php?id=4&sid=2

I'm not randomly generating the problems as I want a lot of control over what is displayed

Answer (score 0):

This first function is the "smart" part because it does all the arithmetic. It does not do simplifying after the fact, so if you end up finding an answer in the loop, it may be worth checking out if 1 is divided by 1, then you could just return 1. But I wanted to keep it this way depending on how you wanted to use it!

```
function simplify(Int $num, Int $denom, Array $primes){
    //going from high primes to low primes
    foreach(array_reverse($primes) as $prime) {
        if (($num % $prime == 0) && ($denom % $prime == 0)) {
            if ($num % $denom == 0) {
                return [intdiv($num,$denom)];
            } elseif ($denom % $num == 0) {
                return [1,intdiv($denom,$num)];
            }
            return [$num / $prime,$denom / $prime];
        }
    }
    return [$num,$denom];
}
```

This next function does the looping through 2 arrays of numbers. It is fairly ugly, I don't usually like nested for loops.

```
function simplifyArrays(Array $arr1, Array $arr2, Array $primes) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){
        $num1 = $arr1[$i];
        for($j=0; $j<count($arr2); $j++){
            $num2 = $arr2[$j];
            echo "simplify: $num1 / $num2 = " . implode("/",simplify($num1,$num2,$primes)) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And to see it in action: https://3v4l.org/qmgJX

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Not sure that works, though. it outputs things like
9 / 9 = 3/3  and simplify: 8 / 4 = 4/2. Not sure why.

Comment: Ok, I added a simple check for cases such as that. If num % denom == 0, then we know we can divide them by each other. Checkout the updated link for results. Furthermore, there were cases such as 4 / 1 that would result in 4 / 1 as an answer. I added 1 to the prime number list and now it accounts for those cases. I know technically it isn't a prime number, but it's ok behind the scenes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, man. There's loads I don't understand in this code, I'm new to this. I think I may have got over my head. I don't quite understand where there arrs1 and arr2 come from. Also, whilst I really appreciate your help, this doesn't actually do quite what I wanted to do.
I want 1:2 as a ratio, then all of it's prime multiples up to a certain point. For instance
2:4, 3:6, 4: 8, ... 11: 22
Then 1:3
2: 6 , 3: 9 ... 11 : 33
Then n : m
Where n and m are all the digits and I want all the prime multiples up to 11 * 

I really don't understand why my code, as inelegant as it is, doesn't work

Comment: It's alright, baby steps! I may have misunderstood what you were looking for. I would recommend not worrying about the storage in a database until you are sure you can get the arithmetic correct. Create a function that takes simple parameters,  such as createPrimeMultiples(int1,int2,PrimeNumberArray). Build an array off of those params. Then the function could be called with params such as createPrimeMultiples(1, 2, [2,3,5,7,11]). You know what it is to output already, [2:4, 3:6, 5:10,...], multiply the first num by the prime number, then the second num by the prime number. You got this!